# How to show text fixed position 2d using FTGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, ftgl

I would like to show some text (a player score and number of lives left) on the top left corner of my panel.

My game is is a pinball game running in openGL, and I would like to use FTGL to show the text.

My code looks like this

```
FTGLTextureFont font("./fonts/JambeticaRegular.ttf");
glTranslatef(-150,50,0);
font.FaceSize(32);
font.Render(text);
```

My problem is that the text follows the pinball table when I move the camera. I want it to be fixed on the upper left corner, never moving, wathever I do with the camera.

Would you have an idea?

EDIT

I tried doing this, instead.

```
FTGLPixmapFont font("./fonts/JambeticaRegular.ttf");
font.FaceSize(30);
font.Render("Points: ", -1, FTPoint(0, 300, 0));
font.Render("Lives: ", -1, FTPoint(0, 270, 0));
```

It works in some way, as my text is now fixed, but it's fixed at a distance from the bottom left corner. I would like to have it fixed to the upper left corner. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

Before rendering text, try setting matrix again using glLoadIdentity and glOrtho.
Or you could save/restore matrices by glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix.

Answer (score 0):

Take the frustum height and width to calculate a relative position to use with  FTPoint().